# How to get my projects back on the "projects" window after clicking "close all projects" in file tab?

Tags: java, netbeans, projects

I have chosen the option "close all projects" in the NetBeans file tab. No more they are showing in my projects window and I'm now wondering how I can get them to show there again.

Comment: ... Simple open the project again ... :/

Answer (score 0):

From Netbeans press Ctrl+Shift+O, go to project location and click "Open project"

Answer (score 0):

You can open your must recently used projects by clicking: `File > Open Recent Projects`, there click the project that you want to open.